# How can I see the Sonos diagnostic trace file?

Tags: sonos

In the Sonos documentation on https://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/224 the following is stated:

> If there is a streaming error, the firmware will also show an error in
>   the diagnostic trace file.

How can I see this diagnostic trace file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace file is visible to Sonos employees. You can submit a diagnostic by following the directions here: https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/142/~/submit-system-diagnostics